# Error while trying to append a list to a csv

Tags: python, csv, append, jupyter

I´m working on jupyter and trying to append the list "data_list" to a csv but the console is giving me this error:

"OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported"

```
with open('files/datasets/output/Personas_Mercantil_1.csv', 'a') as fd:

    writer = csv.writer(fd, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(data_list)
```

P.S.: I'm working with an ec2 r5.2xlarge Amazon instance

Comment: Indentation matters - indent `writer` lines.

Comment: Sorry, in my code it is well indented, i will edit it

Comment: Ok, do you have write permissions to that location?

Comment: Running `ls -l` in the terminal is one way to find out if you have write permission.

Comment: It says I have this permissons: -rw-r--r-- 1